# How to set non-style values like "loop" or "autoplay" in CSS?

Tags: css, html5-video

How can I set properties that aren't under "style" in CSS?

I'm using a lot of HTML video that I want to autoplay. In my HTML I write something like:

```
<video src="avideo.webm" loop autoplay></video>
```

But I want to set the loop and autoplay to "true" in CSS. How can I do this? The following doesn't work:

```
video { loop: true; autoplay: true; }
```

I realised that this would be the case for all properties that are not part of "style". Does CSS not have the power to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No. CSS is only styling.

Answer (score 0):

No way. You should use javascript / jQuery for dynamic setting attributes value.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the name of the language really, **CSS** means ***C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heet(s)*

This implies that it's used for styling (and a specific hierarchy of doing so too).

HTML attributes should always be added through HMTL itself or dynamically assigned by JS since these are properties that go *beyond* styling like the ones you mentioned `loop` and `autoplay`.